# golang sort part of a slice using sort.Slice

Tags: sorting, go, slice

It's easy to sort a slice using sort.Slice in Golang, for example

```golang
func sortAll(nums []int) {
    sort.Slice(nums, func(i, j int) bool {
        if nums[i] < nums[j] {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

input : `[]int{2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2}`
output:`[0 0 1 1 2 2 2 2]`

It works great.

However, if I want to sort a slice from some certain position, which means I just want to sort part of the slice. I used this piece of code:

```
func sortPartly(nums []int, p int) {
    sort.Slice(nums[p:], func(i, j int) bool {
        if nums[i] < nums[j] {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

With the same input, I use `sortPartly(nums, 1)` to set the position to start sorting to be 1. And I got output `[2 0 1 1 2 2 2 0]` which isn't in order from `nums[1]`,the output should be `[2 0 0 1 1 2 2 2]`

After some debugging, I happend to write this piece of code below, it worked just as I wanted. But I don't understand why this code works

```golang
func sortPartly(nums []int, p int) {
    sort.Slice(nums[p:], func(i, j int) bool {
        if nums[i+p] < nums[j+p] {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

I have a toy code  to save your time, can anyone help me explain why this code works. [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/VV0vnFrJQVw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code that works from the question:

```
func sortPartly(nums []int, p int) {
    sort.Slice(nums[p:], func(i, j int) bool {
        if nums[i+p] < nums[j+p] {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

This function sorts the slice `nums[p:]`.  This slice shares a backing array with `nums`, but uses different indices for the elements in that backing array.  The element at index 0 is at index `p` in `nums`. The element at index 1 is at index `p + 1` in `nums` and so on.  Because sort.Slice uses indices into the slice `nums[p:]` and the anonymous function refers to slice `nums`, the anonymous function must adjust the indices by adding `p`.

Eliminate the index adjustment by declaring the slice to sort.  Refer to that slice in the anonymous function.

```
func sortPartly(nums []int, p int) {
    t := nums[p:]
    sort.Slice(t, func(i, j int) bool {
        if t[i] < t[j] {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

Note that `t` shares a backing array with `nums`.  Sorting `t` sorts elements in `nums`.

Bonus suggestion: Simplify the construct `if boolValue { return true } else { return false }` to `return boolValue`.

```
func sortPartly(nums []int, p int) {
    t := nums[p:]
    sort.Slice(t, func(i, j int) bool {
        return t[i] < t[j]
    })
}
```